# where in android source code can I find native_drawBitmap() for Canvas?

Tags: android, performance, canvas

I encountered a performance issue concerning `Canvas`, and in order to find out why `Canvas.drawBitmap()` is slow (as slow as 60ms) in my situation, I decided to look into its source code.
Now I have found the java source code of `Canvas`, and its member function `drawBitmap()` calls `native_drawBitmap`, and I want to go further to look into `native_drawBitmap`, but can't find source code of it.
Where is the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/12830122). Search for `native_drawBitmap`.

Cheers